# My Score adds to much every single time rectangle collides with other rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to make it so that if my rectangle collides with an another rectangle/Point, it will move the Point y position away from the rectangle and will add one to my score. The problem that I'm getting is that my score will add two instead of one evey single time my rectangle collides with my point https://gyazo.com/d9e4167f749f2a672fe7f713ce5bab2e. I have tried using a true and false statement to make it only add one instead of two to my score and that also did not work. I have also tried using a timer to tell it when to add and that did not work for me to.

This is what I tried

```
    if point:
        score += 1
        text = font.render(""+str(score), True,(0,0,0))
        point = False
        
    # Making the rectangles get off the screen for a short amount of time
    if Ptimer > 0:
        Ptimer += 1
        point1.y = -200
    if Ptimer >= 15:
        Ptimer = 0
        

    if Ptimer2 > 0:
        Ptimer2 += 1
        point2.y = -200
    if Ptimer2 >= 20:
        Ptimer2 = 0

    # The player collideing with the point's
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(point1.rect):
        Ptimer = 1
        point = True

    if playerman.rect.colliderect(point2.rect):
        Ptimer2 = 1
        point = True
```

My full code

```
import pygame,random
pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 600
# Screen width and height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
# Name of the Screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
# The background
background = pygame.image.load("img/BG_2.png").convert_alpha()

# Making both peipes separate 
Pipe_distance = 830
# part of making background shift
bg_shift = 0

# player class
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.normal = [pygame.image.load("img/Normal_fish" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(1,7)]
        self.up = [pygame.image.load("img/Up_fish" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(1,7)]
        self.down = [pygame.image.load("img/Down_fish" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(1,7)]
        self.speed = 5
        self.JumpCount = False
        self.isJump = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.direction = "up"
        self.direction = "down"
        self.direction = "normal"
        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.fps = 10
        self.normal = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5, image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.normal]
        self.up = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5, image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.up]
        self.down = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5, image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.down]
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "normal":
            image_list = self.normal
        elif self.direction == "up":
            image_list = self.up
        elif self.direction == "down":
            image_list = self.down
        # Telling when to change frames
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
            # The time until next frame
            inter_time_delay = 1000 // self.fps
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
            # Changing it to the next frame
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0

        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx
        player_rect.centery
        window.blit(player_image,player_rect)


# Pipe class
class Pipe:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 3
        self.pipe = pygame.image.load("img/chain.png").convert_alpha()
        self.pipe = pygame.transform.scale(self.pipe,(self.pipe.get_width()//2, self.pipe.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.anim_index = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        pipe_rect = self.pipe.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        pipe_rect.centerx += 10
        pipe_rect.centery += 595
        window.blit(self.pipe,pipe_rect)

# Pipe2 class
class Pipe2:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 3
        self.pipe = pygame.image.load("img/chain.png").convert_alpha()
        self.pipe = pygame.transform.scale(self.pipe,(self.pipe.get_width()//2, self.pipe.get_height()//2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.anim_index = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        pipe_rect = self.pipe.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        pipe_rect.centerx += 26
        pipe_rect.centery -= 635
        window.blit(self.pipe,pipe_rect)

# Partical class
class Partical:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x =  x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.par = [pygame.image.load("img/Partical" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(1,8)]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.fps = 10
        self.play = False
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.direction = "par"
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        if self.direction == "par":
            image_list = self.par
            
        # Is it time to show next frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
            # Time  until the next frame
            inter_time_delay = 750 // self.fps
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
            # Show the next frame
            if self.play:
                self.anim_index += 1
                if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                    self.anim_index = 0

        if self.play:
            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0
        par_image = image_list[self.anim_index]
        window.blit(par_image,self.rect)

# Point class
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 3
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Color
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
# Calss's cords,size, and color
playerman = Player(200,250,40,40,white)

pipe1 = Pipe(350,900,60,700,green)
pipe2 = Pipe2(350,-900,60,700,green)
pipe3 = Pipe(720,9900,60,700,white)
pipe4 = Pipe2(720,-9900,60,700,blue)
par = Partical(-300,350,50,50,blue)
point1 = Point(400,-300,40,70,white)
point2 = Point(770,-300,40,70,white)

# All my list
pipes = [pipe1,pipe3]
pipes2 = [pipe2,pipe4]
particals = [par]
points = [point1,point2]

# Point system
font = pygame.font.Font("img/CAT.ttf",60)
score = 0
text = font.render(""+str(score), True,(0,0,0))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = ((250,60))
# Displaying class's in main loop
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    window.blit(background,(0,0))

    # Part of making background move
    bg_width = background.get_width()
    bg_offset = bg_shift % bg_width 
    
    window.blit(background, (-bg_offset, 0)) 
    window.blit(background, (bg_width - bg_offset, 0)) 

    # Drawing my classes and other things
    playerman.draw()

    for Pipe in pipes:
        Pipe.draw()
    for Pipe2 in pipes2:
        Pipe2.draw()
    for Partical in particals:
        Partical.draw()
    for Point in points:
        Point.draw()
    window.blit(text,textRect)


# To make the game more difuclt
ptimer = 0
# for playing sprite when player jumps
Jumping = 0
# Making it so the rectangle dose not come for a whilw
Ptimer = 0
Ptimer2 = 0
point = False
fps = 35
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    
    # Making most of my classes move
    for Pipe in pipes:
        Pipe.x  -= Pipe.speed
    for Pipe2 in pipes2:
        Pipe2.x -= Pipe2.speed
    for Pipe2 in pipes2:
        if Pipe2.x <= -200:
            Pipe2.x = 550
    for Point in points:
        Point.x -= Point.speed
    for Point in points:
        if Point.x <= -200:
            Point.x = 550
        
    # Moving backgrond
    bg_shift += 2

    # Randomizing pipe
    for Pipe in pipes:
        if Pipe.x <= -200:
            Pipe.x = 550
            Pipe.y = random.randint(150,500)
            pipe2.y = pipe1.y - Pipe_distance
            pipe4.y = pipe3.y - Pipe_distance
            point1.y = pipe1.y - 90
            point2.y = pipe3.y - 90


    if point:
        score += 1
        text = font.render(""+str(score), True,(0,0,0))
        point = False
        
    # Making the rectangles get off the screen for a short amount of time
    if Ptimer > 0:
        Ptimer += 1
        point1.y = -200
    if Ptimer >= 15:
        Ptimer = 0
        

    if Ptimer2 > 0:
        Ptimer2 += 1
        point2.y = -200
    if Ptimer2 >= 20:
        Ptimer2 = 0

    # The player collideing with the point's
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(point1.rect):
        Ptimer = 1
        point = True

    if playerman.rect.colliderect(point2.rect):
        Ptimer2 = 1
        point = True
        

    # Making the game faster
    ptimer += 1
    if ptimer == 3000:
        for Pipe in pipes:
            for Pipe2 in pipes2:
                for Point in points:
                    Pipe.speed += 1
                    Pipe2.speed += 1
                    Point.speed += 1
        bg_shift += 1
    if ptimer == 6000:
        for Pipe in pipes:
            for Pipe2 in pipes2:
                for Point in points:
                    Pipe.speed += 1
                    Pipe2.speed += 1
                    Point.speed += 1
        bg_shift += 3

        
    # If the player collides with the chain
    for Pipe in pipes:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Pipe.rect):
            print("collide")
    for Pipe2 in pipes2:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Pipe2.rect):
            print("collide2")

    # Mostly about player direction
    if Jumping > 0:
        Jumping += 1
        playerman.direction = "up"
        for Partical in particals:
            Partical.x = playerman.x + 10
            Partical.y = playerman.y + 25
            Partical.play = True
    if Jumping >= 15:
        playerman.direction = "normal"
        Partical.y = -200
        Partical.anim_index = 0
    if Jumping >= 20:
        Jumping = 0
        playerman.direction = "down"
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        Jumping = 1

    collide = False

    playerman.y += playerman.speed
    # bird moving
    if not playerman.isJump:
        # [...]

        # the bird is allowed to jump even if it is not colliding:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            playerman.isJump = True

        if collide:
            playerman.fall = 0

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            
            # if K_SPACE is pressed, then the bird keeps jumping
            if not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = False


    
    
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the `y` attribute of the object when you move it out of the visible area:

> ```py
> point1.y = -200
> ```

However you use the `rect` attribute for the collision test:

> ```py
> if playerman.rect.colliderect(point1.rect):
> ```

Hence, you need to update the `rect` attribute after changing the `y` attribute before the next collision test is performed:

```py
if Ptimer > 0:
    Ptimer += 1
    point1.y = -200
    point1.rect.topleft = (point1.x, point1.y)
```